# How do I Create a Sequence of Circles In a GUI Java Program

Tags: java, user-interface, graphics

I am amateur programmer currently working on Exercise C.2 in the Second Edition of the Think Java Book [(page 348 of the PDF)](http://greenteapress.com/thinkjava6/thinkjava2.pdf). The goal of the exercise is to modify a programmed named [Mickey.java](https://github.com/ChrisMayfield/ThinkJavaCode2/blob/master/appc/Mickey.java) so that will display the following:

[image: The output of the program]

My code is below:

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Exercise_Two extends Canvas {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Exercise_Two");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Canvas canvas = new Exercise_Two();
        canvas.setSize(400, 400);
        canvas.setBackground(Color.white);
        frame.add(canvas);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Rectangle bb = new Rectangle(100, 100, 200, 200);
        Exercise_Two(g, bb);
    }


    /* Draws a circle given Graphics and Rectangle */
    public void boxOval(Graphics g, Rectangle bb) {   
        g.fillOval(bb.x, bb.y, bb.width, bb.height);
    }


    public void Exercise_Two(Graphics g, Rectangle bb) { 

        boxOval(g, bb); // Draws a circle whose center is in the middle of the screen  

        int hx = bb.width / 2;
        int hy = bb.height / 2;

        // Rectangle(x, y, width, height)
        Rectangle half = new Rectangle(bb.x, bb.y, hx, hy);

        half.translate(-hx / 2, -hy / 2);
        boxOval(g, half);

        half.translate(hx * 2, 0);
        boxOval(g, half);

        /* SOME NOTES TO REMEMBER:
         * - translate by a factor of 4, but set size by a factor of 2 */

        int circle = 4;
        int distance = 2;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {

              System.out.println(distance);

            // The Set-up and making the first circle 
            half.translate(-(hx * distance), 0);

            hx /= 2; hy /= 2;
            half.translate(-hx / 2, -hy / 2);
            half.setSize(hx, hy);
            boxOval(g, half);

            // Making the other circles 
            for (int j = 0; j < circle - 1; j++) {
                 half.translate(hx * 2, 0);
                 boxOval(g, half);  
            }

            circle *= 2;
            distance *= 3;

        }

    }

}
```

I utilized a for loop i to determine how many times the Mickey Symbols will be displayed. The code seems to work well when I set the for loop to end when i < 1 or i < 2.

When i < 1:

[image]

When i < 2:

[image]

However, the output doesn't turn out as planned when i < 3:

[image]

With that being said, is it possible if you give me feedback on the code, showing me what I did wrong when writing the program? I know that there are answers to this exercise online, but I feel it's best for me to see what I'm currently doing wrong in order to learn from it.

Thank you,

Comment: One hint: rephrase your question title to say something meaningful. Everyone coming here has some sort of problem and is looking for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you do not provide the precision required for that task...

> SOME NOTES TO REMEMBER: - translate by a factor of 4, but set size by a factor of 2

this leads to some issue, say we have a width=100 and divide it 2 times by 4:

> 100 / (2*4) = 12.5

but the value calculated is **12** because `hx` is of `int`.

back, when drawing you translate the circle 8 times which results

> 8 * 12 = 96

so you are already loosing **4** pixels in interation 1

but these 4 pixels are not yet visible but the further you go the bigger gets the mistake...

### solution

provide more precision on your calculation:

```
double hx = bb.width / 2d; //provide double precision everywhere!
double hy = bb.height / 2d;

...
hx /= 2d; hy /= 2d; //provide double precision everywhere!
half.translate(-hx / 2d, -hy / 2d);
...

double circle = 4d;
double distance = 2d;
```

### programming hints

once you have provided your math with proper precision, you have to turn them back into plain `Integer`s again. This technique is called *type casting*, you use the brackets for this.

```
//high precision calculations with doubles
double hx = bb.width / 2d;
double hy = bb.height / 2d;

//less precise int values
int newWidth = (int)hx;  //use brackets to type cast from double to int
int newHeight = (int)hy; 
Rectangle half = new Rectangle(bb.x, bb.y, newWidth, newHeight);
```

you may loose precision during this process!
`int x = (int) 1.2;` will result into `x = 1`
keep that in mind and use always highest precision for calculations and *type cast* these values only for printing (drawing).

Comment: Thank you very much for the help Martin Frank - because of your help I'm starting to understand what I need to do to fix the code. However, I'm having a bit of trouble implementing your corrections. When I change hx and hy to a double, I get an error on line 41, which contains `  Rectangle half = new Rectangle(bb.x, bb.y, hx, hy); `, as I am unable to use doubles as a parameter for the Rectangle constructor. With that being said, is it possible if you can go over in a bit more detail on how I can implement your corrections?

Comment: it is possible to convert 'double' to 'int' and vice versa.use brackets to caste the more precise primitive into another...  `double x = 1.2; int y = (int)x;` will compile...